# Ring generated by $\Bbb Z$ and several rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I want to show that the ring generated by $\Bbb Z$ and several rational numbers is in fact generated by $\Bbb Z$ and a single rational number whose numerator is $1$.

In case of group it is simple since any subgroup of a cylic group is cyclic, but I've got no idea here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, it suffices to deal with the case $\mathbb Z \left[\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d} \right]$, where $(a,b)=1=(c,d)$

You should show that this is equal to $\mathbb Z\left[\frac{1}{bd} \right]$.

One inclusion is trivial. For the other one, notice that there is some integer $n$ with $na \equiv 1 \pmod b$, i.e. $n\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb Z + \frac{1}{b}$, which shows $\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Z \left[\frac{a}{b}\right]$ (and of course the same works with $\frac{1}{d}$).

---

Actually the latest argument shows $\mathbb Z \left[\frac{a}{b}\right]=\mathbb Z \left[\frac{1}{b}\right]$ and we can use this directly to compute

$$\mathbb Z \left[\frac{a_1}{b_1}, \dotsc, \frac{a_n}{b_n}\right] = \mathbb Z \left[\frac{1}{b_1}, \dotsc, \frac{1}{b_n}\right] = \mathbb Z \left[\frac{1}{b_1 \dotsb b_n}\right].$$

Comment: Very nice. Thanks